# how to remove redirect div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have 5 tabs a b c d e
     and also i have 5 ul list
    that menu a have 1ul and b have another ul etc....including dropdownmenu also

can i click "c" tab menu mean

"c" Tab- sub "ul" display- it's also have drop down menu

can i click this drop down menu mean
   tab"c" is highlight but "a's" ul is redirect

can i click any ul drop down list mean "a's" ul is redirect

how can i remove redirect ul this all ul is inside of seperate div

how can i fix this issue.

```
jquery:

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
        $("ul.topMenu li").click(function () {
            $("ul.topMenu li").removeClass("acB");
            $(this).addClass("acB");

        });


        $('#menu li').click(function () {
            $('#menu li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass('active');
            location.href = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#a").click(function () {

            $("#1div ul").show();
            $("#2div ul").hide();
            $("#3div ul").hide();
            $("#4div ul").hide();
            $("#5div ul").hide();


        });
        $("#b").click(function () {

            $("#2div ul").show();
            $("#1div ul").hide();
            $("#3div ul").hide();
            $("#4div ul").hide();
            $("#5div ul").hide();



        });
        $("#c").click(function () {
            $("#1div ul").hide();
            $("#2div ul").hide();
            $("#4div ul").hide();
            $("#5div ul").hide();
            $("#3div ul").show();


        });
        $("#d").click(function () {
            $("#2div ul").hide();
            $("#1div ul").hide();
            $("#3div ul").hide();
            $("#4div ul").show();
            $("#5div ul").hide();



        });
        $("#f").click(function () {
            $("#2div ul").hide();
            $("#1div ul").hide();
            $("#3div ul").hide();
            $("#4div ul").hide();
            $("#5div ul").show();



        });
    });
    </script>
```

all div have a same id name  "#menu" and its active class is "active"

tab active class "acB"

i have only one problem redirect the 1div ul.how can i remove it

Comment: Not an answer but just a tip: To commit the same operation on multiple selectors, use commas, for example: `$("#1div ul, #2div ul, #3div ul, #4div ul").hide();`

Comment: Please post HTML code using http://jsfiddle.net/ so we con help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove the redirect submenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929605/how-to-remove-the-redirect-submenu). Please don't post the same question more than once.